# Center text in <li> while still keeping list items on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a vertical navigation list on a site but my text isn't centered within the div. Multiple posts on here have suggested to make the list display:table and the items display:table-cell

this solves the problem but I have to change the display from block, which forces each list item to be a new line ( what I want ).

How can I solve this while keeping everything nice, centered, and on a new line?

should note:  It may be firefox but I'm even using a css reset. The issue acts the same with or without the reset. puu .sh /kcrhs/bb728e4711 .png

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #801918;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  Font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav ul li {
  transition: .5s;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Resume</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried above code it display menu in the center of screen did you not get this ?

Comment: No, It may be firefox but I'm even using a css reset. The issue acts the same with or without the reset.

puu .sh  /kcrhs/bb728e4711  .png

Comment: make your #nav{display:table} ul{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle} li{display:block}

Comment: Are you saying you want it vertically centered within the `li`? I see it horizontally centered

Comment: I did want it to be vertically centered. I realized I just needed to split my padding between top and bottom instead of bottom only. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was adjust my padding so that it was even between padding-top and padding-bottom.